# loading image into div, but showing image bytes

Tags: jquery

I wanted to load a web image into my div, and I did this by accident :

```
$.get( picURL, function( data ) {
        $("#myImg").attr({src: data});
});
```

All I had to do was

```
$("#myImg").attr({src: picURL});
```

but in the first case, I got a bunch of bytes showing up.. Jsut wanted to know why this is happenning, and how come it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure  changing the ing id src  and not some wrapper?

Comment: WHy are you saying "load a web image into my div"? Sure #myImg was a img ID and not a div ID?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Like Seriously? You are trying to make a GET request to the Image File and doing nothing with the data returned. What kind of a code is this?

Comment: What does "bytes showing up" mean? What does a byte look like?

Comment: I mean I get to  see the image binary code